# TPL Dataflow execution output order

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In the below test code, I am expecting this outcome:

```
1, 2000
2, 4000
3, 6000
```

However the actual outcome is:

```
3, 6000    
2, 4000
1, 2000
```

Moreover, i only see the outcome on screen after 6 seconds. Which means anything input that is competed is waiting and processed to the next stage.

How can i make the pipeline to spit out the result per input a soon as is completed?

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        Func<int, string> fn = n =>
        {
            var sleep = n * 2000;
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            return n + ", " + sleep;
        };

        var opts = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
        };

        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string>(fn, opts);
        var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<string>(opts);

        transformBlock.LinkTo(bufferBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--)
            transformBlock.Post(i);

        Console.WriteLine(bufferBlock.Receive());
        Console.WriteLine(bufferBlock.Receive());
        Console.WriteLine(bufferBlock.Receive());
    }
```

Comment: That's not the *output* order. That's the execution order of four concurrent tasks. ActionBlock has no output. If you used *transformblock* on the other hand that linked eg to a BufferBlock, you'd see that the results come out in order

Comment: BTW you are forcibly putting *all* TransformBlock tasts to sleep for up to 6 seconds. With only 3 messages starting from the one with the largest delay, a wait of 6 seconds is guaranteed

Comment: Finally, the input is `3, 2, 1`. That's what `for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--)` produces. There's no reason to expect `1,2,3` as the result. What do you really want to do? Ensure the order, or are you OK with returning results out of order?

Comment: i updated source code to use buffer, and still getting same results. also i am not getting how am i putting all the TransformBlock to sleep for 6 sec. they are supposed to be running in parallel

Comment: There's nothing strange about the results. They *are* running in parallel, the order *is* preserved. You are posting the messages in reverse, so you get results in reverse. If they *didn't* run in parallel you'd get 9 seconds of delay. Right now, in order to preserve order the first result has to match the first message which is forced to wait for 6 seconds. By that time all other results are ready and waiting their turn

Answer (score 5):

By default, data flow preserves the order of messages even if they are processed in parallel.

To transform the messages as fast as possible, i.e. out of order, set `EnsureOrdered` to `false` in the options of your `TransformBlock`.

Be sure to use an up to date version of dataflow (currently the nuget package `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` exists in version 4.9), as `EnsureOrdered` has not always been around.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>( x =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep( x );
            return x;
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {EnsureOrdered = false, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10} );
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>( x => Console.WriteLine( x ) );
        transformBlock.LinkTo( actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
        for( var i = 9; i > 0; i-- )
            transformBlock.Post( i * 1000 );
        transformBlock.Complete();
        actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
6000
7000
8000
9000
```

Comment: I could not find EnsureOrdered via VisualStudio ObjectBrowser, i am using .NET 4.6.2 & DataFlow v4.5.24.0. Although I found it here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlockOptions.cs

Comment: Which nuget are you using? `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow`?

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` Assembly from `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` nuget.

Comment: There's a difference between `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` nuget (current) and `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` nuget (old).

Comment: I was using this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/ but i found a newer one https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/. and now it works...thanks